# Trouble understanding what to do PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, logic

We're learning Cursors in class and the first problem I have I believe I understand which asks:

> *Set up an inventory table and a transaction table that has sales, returns, and purchases (the transaction table should have a code with S for sales, R for returns and P for purchases). Create scripts to create and insert data into these tables.*

I believe I just set up a Table and produce some PLSQL so that I'll be able to input into each row. The following question is worded a bit more  ambiguously saying

> *Using the tables you created in the fourth problem, process the transactions and determine the impact on inventory. Display information that gives the original inventory and the inventory after the sales, returns and purchases have been processed. You need to use cursors.*

How would I break this problem down? Thank you for any help.

EDIT: I believe I'm also to be using PROCEDURES with the cursors but still just as lost.

Comment: "You need to use cursors".  That is really sad.

Comment: Yeah I'm really stressed trying to understand what to do.

Comment: What you know about cursors? If you get more knowledge about them you'll find out points in your task where cursors could be used. If you more detailed answer show us , what you had achieved, some code samples, and points where you stucked.

Comment: Have a look at the examples in the documentation for [Cursor FOR loops](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm). btw a lot of the examples in the docs name their cursors `c1` which has always seemed to me the most useless name imaginable. There is also no need to write database code in uppercase like the examples. Be a rebel :)

Comment: You (and/or maybe also your teacher) should learn the difference between an explicit cursor and an implicit cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a tool to run SQL commands in and you are familiar with how to use it.  If not you will need to get that tool first.  Something like the sqlplus client if you want to do it all command line style, or something like Oracle's SQL Developer if you want the friendly GUI.

1. **Create the tables.**  Google "oracle create table examples".  These will be DDL statements and do not need a commit.  You should create at least two constraints.  One for a primary key and one for a foreign key that references the primary key.  Google "oracle contraint examples".
2. **Insert data into the tables.**  Google "oracle insert exemples".  The constraints should do their job and make sure you don't insert orphaned data.  A COMMIT is necessary to make the inserted data permanent.
3. **Create the procedure.**  Google "oracle stored procedure examples".  This will process your transactions.  You will use the S,P, or R codes to determine adding or subtracting from inventory.  You will be using your CURSOR here and most likely a FOR LOOP.  You might use the DBMS.OUTPUT.PRINTLN statement to output the transaction information.  You will find that  thinking through the logic flow of the procedure will influence how your tables are designed in step 1.  As a result, you may end up dropping and recreating your tables and constraints several times.
4. **Run your procedure.**  You may want to avoid a commit in the procedure until you have tested it and are getting the results you want back.  This way you can execute a ROLLBACK statement to put the data back into the state it was before the procedure ran (edit, run, rollback; edit, run, rollback; etc.)
5. **Output results.** If you didn't get all your output requirements done in the procedure, you will need to get that from your tables using the SQL SELECT statement after the procedure runs.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Generally folks do not like to answer these kinds of questions because they are obviously generated by a need to complete a school assignment.  I won't complete your assignment, but will answer your question about CURSORS.

Curses are used in PL/Sql procedures, functions and packages to store a pointer to the result of a query.  For example:

```
-- You cannot use a REF CURSOR directly, you need to create variable that is a REF CURSOR TYPE
-- I use a Type to declare a REF CURSOR
Type MyDataCursor is REF CURSOR;
-- And then declare a variable of that type 
pDataOut MyDataCursor;
-- You then can use the cursor in code
Open pDataOut FOR Select * from sometable
```

This will retrieve data from a table, you can now access that data in several ways.  The most common is to fetch the data and store it in a structure that matches the table row structure.  For example:

```
FETCH MyDataCursor INTO MyDataRowStructure;
```

The structure would mimic all the data columns in one row of the table, for example:

```
-- This particular structure is a TYPE of RECORD
TYPE MyDataRowStructure IS RECORD (
      ID        NUMBER,
      Name      NUMBER,
      Address   VARCHAR2(50),
      City      VARCHAR2(50),
      State     Varchar2(2),
      ZIP       Varchar2(5)
    );
```

Lastly you would want to loop through all the rows of data retrieved from the table and do something with them.  For example:

```
--You start with the first fetch
FETCH MyDataCursor INTO MyDataRowStructure;
-- Now loop through all the rows
WHILE MyDataCursor %FOUND LOOP
-- Do some stuff here with the first row, then fetch the next row ....
FETCH MyDataCursor INTO MyDataRowStructure;
END LOOP;
```

This should get you started.

Comment: In your example I think `Type MyDataCursor is REF CURSOR;` should be `MyDataCursor sys_refcursor;` Also an explicit fetch would be unusual outside certain specific scenarios (bulk collect, single-row lookup and record needed outside loop come to mind) but who knows what the course tutor has in mind.

Comment: Either way works, I've been using `Type MyDataCursor is REF CURSOR` for over 30 years in millions of lines of code.  `sys_refcursor`, to me, is relatively recent.  I wanted to use simple code for a beginner, `fetch` is simple to understand.

Comment: You were declaring ref cursors in PL/SQL in 1987? I don't recall seeing one until Forms 3.0 in the early 90s. In any case, in your example `MyDataCursor` is a type.

Comment: Somewhere around there, don't remember exactly when, Oracle 8i if I remember correctly and I may not.  Worked for the Navy since '87, retired now, I was the first to introduce Oracle to my command, it eventually became the Navy standard and they got a Navy wide site license.  Wish I could take credit for that decision, but it was made way over my pay grade, but I certainly supported it!  I still code PL/Sql today along with VB.NET, C#, javascript, etc. for my own company.  I have never used sys_refcursor in a procedure.  MyDataCursor is derived from a type and like I said, works fine.

Comment: 1987 would have been Oracle 5. PL/SQL arrived in [1988 with Oracle 6](http://www.dadbm.com/roadmap-oracle-database-releases/) (or Forms 3.0 in effect, as the DB had no stored code and PL/SQL cost extra). But we digress. In your example you can't `Open MyDataCursor` because `MyDataCursor` is a type, not a cursor.

Comment: Oracle 6 sounds about right, I simply cannot remember.  Give it a try, you'll see it works fine.  90% of my code is contained in packages, I declare the REF CURSOR in the package definition and use it over and over, no problem.  I'm currently using Oracle 11g.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143601/discussion-between-prescott-chartier-and-william-robertson).